# Getting value from multiple dropdowns (select option)

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, dropdown

I have several dropdown that I want to send their value to a external .php. The problem is how can I reference the value from the drop down and ID which dropdown was used. Hope I have explained it well enough.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script>
         function sayHelloWorld()
         {
           var x = document.getElementById("myDropDown").selectedIndex;
           window.location.href = "externalPHPfile.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + stuff;
         }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    for($x=0;$x<4;$x++)
    {
                      echo("
                       <section>
                       <select  id='myDropDown' onchange='sayHelloWorld()'>
                       <option value='' disabled selected>CHOOSE&nbsp;ONE</option>
                       <option id='' value='cows'>COWS</option>
                       <option id='' value='pigs'>PIGS</option>
                       <option id='' value='chicks'>CHICKS</option>
                       </select>
                       </section>
                         ");
    }

  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ids are singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>

    <script>
     function sayHelloWorld(elem)
     {
       var x = elem.selectedIndex;
       window.location.href = "externalPHPfile.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + stuff;
     }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<?php

for($x=0;$x<4;$x++)
{
                  echo("
                   <section>
                   <select  id='myDropDown' onchange='sayHelloWorld(this)'>
                   <option value='' disabled selected>CHOOSE&nbsp;ONE</option>
                   <option id='' value='cows'>COWS</option>
                   <option id='' value='pigs'>PIGS</option>
                   <option id='' value='chicks'>CHICKS</option>
                   </select>
                   </section>
                     ");
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does not seem to go to external page.

Answer (score 1):

Ids are singular so you can not select an individual one by what you picked. There are many ways of doing it, one way is to pass the event and read the target.

```js
function sayHelloWorld(event) {
  var sel = event.target,  //the select that was active
      selIndex = sel.selectedIndex,  
      value = sel.options[selIndex].value;
  console.log(selIndex, value);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <select id='myDropDown1' onchange='sayHelloWorld(event)'>
    <option value='' disabled selected>CHOOSE&nbsp;ONE</option>
    <option id='' value='cows'>COWS</option>
    <option id='' value='pigs'>PIGS</option>
    <option id='' value='chicks'>CHICKS</option>
  </select>
</section>
<section>
  <select id='myDropDown2' onchange='sayHelloWorld(event)'>
    <option value='' disabled selected>CHOOSE&nbsp;ONE</option>
    <option id='' value='cows'>COWS</option>
    <option id='' value='pigs'>PIGS</option>
    <option id='' value='chicks'>CHICKS</option>
  </select>
</section>
```

You can pass the current object with `this`

```js
function sayHelloWorld(sel) {
  var selIndex = sel.selectedIndex,  
      value = sel.options[selIndex].value;
  console.log(selIndex, value);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <select id='myDropDown1' onchange='sayHelloWorld(this)'>
    <option value='' disabled selected>CHOOSE&nbsp;ONE</option>
    <option id='' value='cows'>COWS</option>
    <option id='' value='pigs'>PIGS</option>
    <option id='' value='chicks'>CHICKS</option>
  </select>
</section>
<section>
  <select id='myDropDown2' onchange='sayHelloWorld(this)'>
    <option value='' disabled selected>CHOOSE&nbsp;ONE</option>
    <option id='' value='cows'>COWS</option>
    <option id='' value='pigs'>PIGS</option>
    <option id='' value='chicks'>CHICKS</option>
  </select>
</section>
```

Or you can add events without the inline event handler

```js
function sayHelloWorld() {
  var sel = this,
      selIndex = sel.selectedIndex,  
      value = sel.options[selIndex].value;
  console.log(selIndex, value);
}

var sels = document.querySelectorAll('.selNav');
for (var i=0; i<sels.length;i++) {
   sels[i].addEventListener("change", sayHelloWorld);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <select class="selNav" id='myDropDown1'>
    <option value='' disabled selected>CHOOSE&nbsp;ONE</option>
    <option id='' value='cows'>COWS</option>
    <option id='' value='pigs'>PIGS</option>
    <option id='' value='chicks'>CHICKS</option>
  </select>
</section>
<section>
  <select class="selNav" id='myDropDown2' >
    <option value='' disabled selected>CHOOSE&nbsp;ONE</option>
    <option id='' value='cows'>COWS</option>
    <option id='' value='pigs'>PIGS</option>
    <option id='' value='chicks'>CHICKS</option>
  </select>
</section>
```

So than you would change the console.log lines to be

```
window.location.href = "externalPHPfile.php?w1=" + selIndex + "&w2=" + stuff;
```

or

```
window.location.href = "externalPHPfile.php?w1=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "&w2=" + stuff;
```

That is assuming that stuff is valid in your code that you are not showing.

Comment: This is great thanks. Could you explain what the console.log(selIndex, value); is for.

Comment: You do not know what console.log is? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

Comment: Seem that I cant send to external page after
window.location.href = "externalPHPfile.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + stuff;

function sayHelloWorld() {
  var sel = this,
      selIndex = sel.selectedIndex,  
      value = sel.options[selIndex].value;
  console.log(selIndex, value);
}

Comment: What is the error in the console, what is not working? the variable `w` is either going to be `selIndex` (if you want the index) or `value` (if you want the value). I also have no clue what `stuff` is...

Comment: Its just not going to another page - when using alert() - it shows the value is being passed, but just stops there.

Comment: Im just testing the code above - nothing more or less

Comment: Well that code you posted does not have the window.location line in it... You need to put that code in there. I did put it in for the demos to run.

Comment: Done that, but seems to stop before it gets there.

Comment: So open up the console in your developer tools and look for an error message. What is the error message? And how did you mark the other one as an answer if it is not working?